# Going from PostgreSQL JSONField to JSON object in Django template

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I am trying to send a JSON object from a Django PostgreSQL database to a Django template. Here is my models.py

```
# models.py
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

from django.db import models

class Net(models.Model):
    net_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def net_default():
        return {"net_name": "None", "graph_data": "None", "city_data": "None"}

    data = JSONField(default=net_default())

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.net_name
```

Here is my views.py

```
# standard includes
from django.shortcuts import render

# my includes
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

# get nets
from .models import Net

def index(request):
    net_q_set = Net.objects.order_by('net_name')
    context = {
        'nets': net_q_set,
    }
    return render(request, 'viewer/index.html', context)
```

So I have a sidebar in which the user selects a network from the 'nets' JSON object. Then a javascript function which takes the selected network name should iterate through the JSON object to get the network's nodes and get each node's latitude and longitude. I am able to iterate through the names with the following code (this code works and produces what I want):

```
{% for name in nets %}
    <li><a href="javascript:plotMap('{{name}}');">{{name}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

But I am having an issue establishing the JSON object in the javascript script. I have tried:

```
<script>
    var nets = JSON.parse({{ nets }})
    function plotMap(name){ ... };
</script>
```

But I get an error of 'unexpected token &' on the `var nets` line. I am guessing this is from parsing the JSON object. Is there a better way to do this? Or am I making an error I am blind to?

**Edit -- 2** Using @Arpit's solution, I call

```
{% for name in nets %}
    <li><a href='javascript:plotMap({{name.data}});'>{{name}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Then in the `plotMap(net_json)` function I immediately call `alert(net_json.city_data.Perth1.lat);` from my understanding this should make an alert that displays "-31.93333", instead I get an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string". Clicking the debugger link on that shows me:

`plotMap({u'city_data': {u'Alice,Springs': {u'lat': -23.7, u'long': 133.88333}, ...}, u'graph_data': {u'nodes': [u'Perth1', ...], u'links': [[u'Perth1', u'Adelaide1'], ...]'});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your context is not a `jsonfield` attribute, Its a `queryset`. You are trying to give an object `name` in your javascript function rather than giving data attribute which is a jsonfield.

In your existing code if you reference the data attribute then it should work.

```
{% for name in nets %}
    <li><a href="javascript:plotMap('{{name.data|safe}}');">{{name}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

If you just want jsonfield values then you can do

```
net_q_set = Net.objects.order_by('net_name').values('data')
```

EDIT: you can use a method to stringify the json so it would be much easier to use it.

```
class Net(models.Model):
    net_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def net_default():
        return {"net_name": "None", "graph_data": "None", "city_data": "None"}

    data = JSONField(default=net_default())

    @property
    def get_json_data(self):
        return json.dumps(self.data)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.net_name
```

Then in template.

```
<li><a href="javascript:plotMap({{name.get_json_data}});">{{name}}</a></li>
```

Comment: If I do `'{{name.data}}'` then can I dig down to the data I need in the javascript function? Or do I need to pass each as I need them? Example: `<li><a href="javascript:plotMap('{{name.data.graph_data}}', '{{name.data.city_data}}' );">{{name}}</a></li>

Comment: `'{{name.data}}'` will pass json to the function and then you can parse it and use it. If you don't want to loop through the entire data and pass every json object then you can use values method mentioned above or you can use a serializer directly

Comment: I am having trouble parsing. I call the javascript function passing `"{{name.data}}"` then I call `var temp = JSON.parse(net_json);` where `net_json` is the `{{name.data}}`. I get the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at plotMap ((index):349)
    at <anonymous>:1:1" upon further inspection I see that it is having problem with the JSON being: `{u'city_data': {u'Alice,Springs': {u'lat': -23.7, u'long': 133.88333}, ... , u'graph_data': {u'nodes': [u'Perth1', ...], u'links': [[u'Perth1', u'Adelaide1'],..]}}`

Comment: Don't use '{{name.data}}'. Use {{name.data}} and don't use json.parae in your script tag also

Comment: I will edit my post to show more of what's happening now. It seems like the JSON is only being parsed down one level or isn't even being parsed at all and is just `undefined`

Comment: @JamesRolfe try the edit. Also try using safe filter tag as mentioned above

Comment: I ended up figuring this out, but I implemented it in a much less elegant way. Also, thanks for the 'safe' tag tip -- I just looked it up. Now on to adding d3 to leaflet hahaha.

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly related to your question but you would probably like to replace

```
data = JSONField(default=net_default())
```

with

```
data = JSONField(default=net_default)
```

In the first case you invoke `net_default` function and set the return value as  value of `default` argument. This will result in creating a mutable default that is shared between all instances of JSONField.
In the other case you set callable as value of default argument and this will result in invoking the callable and setting its return value as a default for each new instance of the model.

Snippet from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield):

> If you give the field a default, ensure it’s a callable such as dict
>   (for an empty default) or a callable that returns a dict (such as a
>   function). Incorrectly using default={} creates a mutable default that
>   is shared between all instances of JSONField.